# Fitting display math with luatex?

Tags: equations, luatex

I took a latex file and edited it to be more readable on my phone. Specifically, I used the geometry package to typeset it on pages measuring 3x4.  I set the text to be left justified to keep words from running outside of my margins. Now I would like to be able to get the display math to fit in the small paper size. I was editing the overlong display equations one by one, but that is too tedious. I was hoping there was a fix using luatex. I am open to any idea that fits the equations on to the page. For example, a sufficient solution would be to turn every equation into a picture and shrink the picture to fit.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [`breqn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/breqn) package. It does automatic line breaking of display math